# why is there no /proc/bus/usb?

Tags: usb, thinkpad, usbfs

I have an old Thinkpad R32 2658 and I want to use `dfu-util`. The reference documentation starts with the following description:

> To run dfu-util, you need to have /proc/bus/usb mounted and working. The terminal command "ls /proc/bus/usb" should return something similar to, "001 002 003 004 005 devices", it shouldn't be empty. If it is empty, use this command:
>   sudo mount -t usbfs usbfs /proc/bus/usb

The problem is: I don't have /proc/bus/usb at all. In /proc/bus there are only `input` and `pci` sub-directories. But I do have USB ports on my old notebook and my USB keys work well.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this [forum entry](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1432598) and report if this works for you? Please note, the author of the answer states that this is not a long-term solution.

Comment: Find a tool that supports sysfs instead.

Comment: @bender: thanks for the link! This is a workaround that works for me as well :) I hope it won't cause any further problems when using dfu-util, but for now it looks good, thanks again!

Comment: Could you then please write an official answer to your own question for the sake of documentation? And after a day you even will be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: @bender: ok, sorry, I did not know how that works, that was my first question here ;)

Comment: [this link here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1432598) that bender posted provides a nice workaround that works for me, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly a solution but a workaround that worked for the author of the question is available in [this forum entry](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1432598).

Please note, the author of the answer above states that this is not a long-term solution.

Answer (score -1):

In 12.04 (and perhaps before), /usb/bin/usb-devices is a script that provides similar info.

Comment: Not in 13.04, doubtful in later releases.